# What is a quick way to write "dagger" sign in MS Word equation mode?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365, unicode

In MS Word equation mode with the Unicode converter, I write symbols by putting the "\" sign and then typing the specific Unicode, i.e., for the summation sign I write "\sum" and press "space" and I get the summation sign.

But for the "dagger" sign there is no Unicode. Is there any quick and easy way to write it? It takes a lot of time to go to the "Equation" tab and find this sign.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you refer to the
[Dagger (mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(mark)),
it does have a Unicode representation :

```
U+2020 † DAGGER
```

And you also have :

```
U+2021 ‡ DOUBLE DAGGER
```

In larger format (image) :

[image]

The easy method for Word and most Windows applications is to
press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, type `0134` and release
the key.

For more information, see
[this article](https://office-watch.com/2020/dagger-%E2%80%A0-symbol-in-word-excel-powerpoint-and-outlook/).

Comment: thank you for your quick response. Should I write "\U+2021" in equation Unicode mode to get this dagger sign? I am doing it and it is not converting to the dagger. (I am sorry, I am not very good with MS Word)

Comment: There is an easier method for Word : Press and hold the Alt key, type `0134` and release the Alt. For more information, see [this article](https://office-watch.com/2020/dagger-%E2%80%A0-symbol-in-word-excel-powerpoint-and-outlook/).

Comment: @LuqmanSaleem you can also set up your own autocorrect or math autocorrect so that when you type \dag, Word will enter the U+2020 character, and so on. Can be easier to remember! e.g. go to File->Options->Proofing-> Autocorrect on Windows Desktop Word.

Comment: @jonsson OMG. This is the best thing that I have ever found about MS Word. Thank you so so much.

Comment: @harrymc Depending on your operating system and keyboard layout, there may be even easier ways. For example, using the standard Danish keyboard layout on macOS, pressing `Alt` + `T`
 will give you the † character.

Comment: Alt codes are an OS-level feature of Windows, not an app-level feature of Word. By default, any and all apps will see a button press of `†` when you type `0` `1` `3` `4` while holding `Alt` in Windows. It even works in Windows Subsystem Linux, so I can use it in my Ubuntu VM within Windows. (What the app decides to do when that character is typed, of course, is up to the app. And I believe an app can turn this feature off by having its own hooks for the `Alt` key?)

Answer (score 7):

Another strategy which can be useful if you have a bunch of symbols you don't want to memorize the alt codes for, and you're on Windows 10:

If you press <kbd>winkey</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (the windows key and the period at the same time), it will bring up a window where you can select from emojis, emoticons, and various unicode symbols.

[image: A screenshot of the emoji window in Windows 10. The symbols tab is selected, and the first symbol in the history list is the dagger.]

This keeps a history as well, so your most recently used symbols will be remembered, so once you find the dagger the first time, the subsequent uses will be pretty easy to grab.

This works in any window, as well, so you can easily type † into your Stack Overflow answers if you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Tessets solution, but also an alternative.
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Run) and then enter `charmap` and enter.

[image: Character map]